# Importing module from python makes submodules disappear

Tags: python, ipython

I have ipython (0.12.dev) installed and I have noticed that I cannot use it in a project that has a `path` module because of a name collision. This is understandable, but the problem is that when I import the module full path the submodules I care about are not there.

For instance, if I run this in a normal (without `path`) dir:

```
>>> import IPython.external.path
>>> dir(IPython.external.path)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_path', 'path']
```

But if I run it in a project which has a module `path` (or just `mkdir path; touch path/__init__.py`):

```
>>> import IPython.external.path
>>> dir(IPython.external.path)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

The last two submodules (`_path` and `path`) are missing.

Is there a way to access to those modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[path](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py) is a third party library that IPython will try to use if it's present. Unfortunately, that means it tries to use your path module or package when that's in the working directory.

One simple workaround is to start IPython in another directory, and `cd myproject` inside IPython (but then you won't be able to use your path module).

To access the path module shipped with IPython, do `from IPython.external.path import _path`. You could modify `IPython/external/path/__init__.py` so it goes straight to the included copy.

Comment: Thanks, the directory trick worked perfectly. I don't really need the path module from IPython, as long as it is happy with the trick.